# Raspberry pi 4 - Doesn't read sd card

Tags: sd-card, pi-4, noobs, raspberry-pi-os

I am trying to boot noobs, or raspberry os, or lineageos, and i am getting some errors

Error when using sdcard "Failed to open device: 'sdcard' (cmd 371a0010 status lf0f0001)"

booting NOOBS gives me this when booting from sd card

[image: RASPBERRY PROBLEM]

asks for "RESET USB port-power 1000 ms" too

Raspberry os gives me this when booting from sd card, but i can boot via usb

mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising sd card

Lineage os I can't boot from sdcard neither usb and it loops in the same problem as noobs

**Update** with info from a comment:
SHA-256 sum check dont give any error. My boot order is f41. Booting raspberry os from usb drive, i cannot do SD Copier with SD card.

Comment: there's two possibilities ... the sd-card slot isn't working ... or, more likely, the sdcard isn't working - do you have any  details about the sdcard?

Comment: actually, the sd-card slot looks to be working ... when you do successfully boot from USB, can you stick the sd card in and read it?

Comment: didnt test in this way, but i could use noobs from sdcard, but when i install the raspberry os from noobs and i boot the os i get this error "mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising sd card"

Comment: I'd try a different sdcard

Comment: i trying two and they are from sandisk ultra

Comment: Please indicate how you are writing the various images to the SD card.

Comment: I can point out several issues: 1. SD failure (But when you can run NOOBs from it its ruled out). 2. Image file failure (have you downloaded it again and make a SHA-256 sum check). 3. The transfer of the image to SD process has failed. 4. Boot order (f41 indicates SD card as boot media) ref. https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2711_bootloader_config.md and then on to more obscure posibilities later....

Comment: And here is a nice troubleshooting guide: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/raspberry-pi-wont-boot-fix/

Comment: SHA-256 sum check dont give any error. My boot order is f41. Booting raspberry os from usb drive, i cannot do SD Copier with SD card

Comment: Don't use NOOBS. Use the [Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-os/) and [flash it direct from the image](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/linux.md). Then follow [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151) and tell us what of it fails.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation with my RPi 4b, so perhaps this will help you. I tried flashing the image onto the SD card using `dd`, as described in the official RPi guide at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/linux.md using `2021-01-11-raspios-buster-armhf.img` with :

```
$ sha256sum 2021-01-11-raspios-buster-armhf.img
ace32c42e34d94cb175b15820af8bb13bd0b6a5e1360b0f58b9cf9c39013bd1d  2021-01-11-raspios-buster-armhf.img
```

This however did not work.

According to https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151#p1485558 the 4 times short blinking LED stated, that the `start.elf` file of the image was not correct or could not be found. So I concluded, that I would have to try another tool for flashing the image onto the SD card. The tool etcher was recommended, a bloated third party electron tool containing ads =( However, that one worked. It would have been good to have a working image `dd` onto the SD card, as I have done in the past, but alas that was not the case.

So this is my suggestion: Use the bloated etcher tool to write the SD card.

Hint: Then add an empty file `ssh` in the `boot` directory of the image, to be able to access the RPi using SSH. Then set the display resolution (required) in `raspi-conf` and enable VNC in there as well, to be able to access via VNC.

Comment: If `dd` did not write the image correctly to the SD card, there are three possible causes: 1) The image is faulty, 2) There was a hardware failure, 3) You did it wrong.  Beyond your system being compromised or corrupted, there aren't any other possibilities.